Using std::conditional with function types
I am trying to define a function type alias that depends on a template parameter, T.  Specifically the function type is of the form void foo(T) if T is not void, and void foo() if it is void.
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
struct S
{
    template <typename U>
    using F = std::conditional_t<std::is_void_v<U>, std::function<void()>, std::function<void(U)>>;

    F<T> foo;
};


int main()
{
    S<int> i;
    i.foo = [](int x) { std::cout << "fint " << x << std::endl;};
    // i.foo = [](){return;};  // does not compile (good)
    i.foo(1);

    S<void> v;  // ERROR
    v.foo =  []() {return;};
}

Compiler (using C++17) is choking on instantiating the class when T is void.
conditional_ftype.cpp: In substitution of ‘template<class T> template<class U> using F = std::conditional_t<is_void_v<U>, std::function<void()>, std::function<void(U)> > [with U = void; T = void]’:
conditional_ftype.cpp:11:10:   required from ‘struct S<void>’
conditional_ftype.cpp:22:10:   required from here
conditional_ftype.cpp:9:11: error: invalid parameter type ‘void’
    9 |     using F = std::conditional_t<std::is_void_v<U>, std::function<void()>, std::function<void(U)>>;
      |           ^
conditional_ftype.cpp:9:11: error: in declaration ‘using F = std::conditional_t<is_void_v<U>, std::function<void()>, std::function<void(U)> >’


Maybe template <typename... Ts>struct S { std::function<void(Ts...)> foo;}; is more suitable to your needs, with empty pack instead of void.

I find if constexpr can also be really helpful for untangling such custom traits
template <typename T>
struct S
{
    template <typename U>
    static auto FImpl() {
        if constexpr (std::is_void_v<U>)
            return std::function<void()>{};
        else
            return std::function<void(U)>{};
    }

    template <typename U>
    using F = decltype(FImpl<U>());

    F<T> foo;
};

You can order the checks however you want in a fairly readable way, with pretty intuitive semantics.
You can even write the helper inline if you are partial to immediately invoked lambda expressions.
template <typename U>
using F = decltype([]{
    if constexpr (std::is_void_v<U>)
        return std::function<void()>{};
    else
        return std::function<void(U)>{};
}());

While this may impose certain additional requirements on the types we choose (default initialization, for instance), it's rarely a show-stopper in my experience. The initial readability is always a sell for me.
Nevertheless, for completeness' sake, it's not too hard to add a level of indirection that will allow this to work for any type we wish to offer in the trait. Something like std::type_identity will allow us to write our return statements without relying on the properties of the types themselves
template <typename U>
using F = decltype([]{
    if constexpr (std::is_void_v<U>)
        return std::type_identity<std::function<void()>>{};
    else
        return std::type_identity<std::function<void(U)>>{};
}())::type; // fetch the type from std::type_identity<...>


Specialization might be the simplest:
template <typename U>
struct function_1
{
    using type = void(U);
};
template <>
struct function_1<void>
{
    using type = void();
};

template <typename T>
struct S
{
    std::function<typename function_1<T>::type> foo;
};

Demo
